# How to make an MUI 5 checkbox & label change color on hover?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-tsx, css-in-js

I'd like to have a checkbox with a label in a wrapper. When the wrapper is hovered everything should change color. See the image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const styles = {formControlLabel:{
  color:'#d7dae0',
  border: '1px solid white',
  span: {
    color: '#d7dae0', 
    '&:hover':{border: '1px solid red'},
  }
},
}}

export function MyCheckbox(){
  return(
    <FormControlLabel
      control={<Checkbox />}
      label={'test'}
      sx={styles.formControlLabel}
    />
  )
}
```

I've tried many different things, but this is the closest I've come. I can't seem to put a `'&:hover'` on the formControlLabel styles at the top level - it has to be imbedded in another element. Why is that?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-feynman-lzy1e2?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox?

Comment: @sm3sher Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-4zt0t1 You can see the spans change color independently but I'd like them and the border to change when the FormControlLabel is hovered.

Comment: I see neither the lable nor the checkbox in the sandbox

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong, but it keeps reverting to the original. Let me try some things, sorry about that.

Comment: @sm3sher OK, I got it: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-feynman-lzy1e2?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `:hover` to your parent and set `borderColor` in the parent and having `span` inside the `:hover` parent, it will change to red at the same time

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
const styles = {
  formControlLabel: {
    border: "1px solid",
    p: "8px",
    m: "20px",
    "&:hover": {
      borderColor: "red",
      span: {
          color: "red"
      },
    }
  }
};
```